# Recover sass files from map and css

Tags: css, dictionary, sass

I'm just thinking if there is any way to recover some `*.scss` files if we have only `css` and its `map`. Ex.: someday someone removed your scss files :) Is it possible? I know that map helps us to debug our css code and show where it is located in scss. It's a lot of information. But is it enought? Any way to do this?

[image]

Picture above shows that example: sass folder doesn't exist. But browser know what and where is from source map.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this site before to convert css output back to scss formatting. http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/ Not perfect but its a start.